# Stackoverflow in IDE when clientdataset is open

Tags: mysql, delphi, stack-overflow

For a few days I've been trying to resolve this error, simply when running my project I receive a stackoverflow error. The error started when I created a TClientDataSet that has four lookup fields. In debug mode I do not get any information (or something I understand), when Active the Clientdataset in design mode the Delphi XE6 IDE simply crashes and exits.

I use MySQL.

[image]

Here is the TClientDataset definition from the .DFM file:

```
object cdstblocal: TClientDataSet
  Aggregates = <>
  Params = <>
  ProviderName = 'dsptblocal'
  Left = 1048
  Top = 192
  object cdstblocallocId: TIntegerField
    FieldName = 'locId'
    ProviderFlags = [pfInUpdate, pfInWhere, pfInKey]
  end
  object cdstblocallocEst_Id: TIntegerField
    FieldName = 'locEst_Id'
  end
  object cdstblocallocTip_Id: TIntegerField
    FieldName = 'locTip_Id'
  end
  object cdstblocallocBH_Id: TIntegerField
    FieldName = 'locBH_Id'
  end
  object cdstblocallocRio_Id: TIntegerField
    FieldName = 'locRio_Id'
  end
  object cdstblocallocDat_Id: TIntegerField
    FieldName = 'locDat_Id'
    Required = True
  end
  object cdstblocallocNome: TStringField
    FieldName = 'locNome'
    Size = 45
  end
  object cdstblocallocSigla: TStringField
    FieldName = 'locSigla'
    Size = 8
  end
  object cdstblocallocLat: TFloatField
    FieldName = 'locLat'
  end
  object cdstblocallocLong: TFloatField
    FieldName = 'locLong'
  end
  object cdstblocallocAlt: TFloatField
    FieldName = 'locAlt'
  end
  object cdstblocallocComent: TStringField
    FieldName = 'locComent'
    Size = 100
  end
  object cdstblocallocData: TSQLTimeStampField
    FieldName = 'locData'
  end
  object cdstblocallistbh: TStringField
    FieldKind = fkLookup
    FieldName = 'listbh'
    LookupDataSet = cdstbbh
    LookupKeyFields = 'bhId'
    LookupResultField = 'bhNome'
    KeyFields = 'locBH_Id'
    Lookup = True
  end
  object cdstblocallistrio: TStringField
    FieldKind = fkLookup
    FieldName = 'listrio'
    LookupDataSet = cdstbrio
    LookupKeyFields = 'rioId'
    LookupResultField = 'rioNome'
    KeyFields = 'locRio_Id'
    Lookup = True
  end
  object cdstblocallisttip: TStringField
    FieldKind = fkLookup
    FieldName = 'listtip'
    LookupDataSet = cdstblocal_tipo
    LookupKeyFields = 'locTipId'
    LookupResultField = 'locTipNome'
    KeyFields = 'locId'
    Lookup = True
  end
  object cdstblocallistest: TStringField
    FieldKind = fkLookup
    FieldName = 'listest'
    LookupDataSet = cdstblocal_estado
    LookupKeyFields = 'locEstId'
    LookupResultField = 'locEstNome'
    KeyFields = 'locEst_Id'
    Lookup = True
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @JerryDodge, this question is really missing some information. I just put one clientdataset in a datamodule, create lookup fields and click on active, the delphi crash, with no other code write by me. So the problem maybe is in my database.

Comment: What @JerryDodge says.  However, since you say your project in design mode crashes the IDE, it can't be your code (unless you're using any self-written components of course).  One thing you could do is to strip your form (or datamodule)  to the bare minimum and then add the text version of your DFM to your q - that way we might have a chance to reproduce your problem.  Do any of your lookup fields share the same dataset to do their data look-ups?

Comment: Also, check that you haven't managed to connect up your datasets "in a loop".  The IDE will detect that and prevent you if there are only 2 datasets in the loop IIRC, but I'm not sure about more than 2.

Comment: Then change them so that they use different datasets (getting data from the same place); then see if the problem remains.

Comment: I think we also need to see the DFM that contains cdstblocal_tipo and cdstblocal_estado.  See if you can simplify your DFMs and maybe post as a new q if that doesn't identify your problem.

Comment: @MartynA I found the problem, exactly as you mentioned when put more than 2 it crashes. The only way to work out that, is change the table design?

Comment: What I 'd do would be to replace the lookup fields by look-up columns in the SQL used to get the server-side data.  That should get your project to behave in the IDE.  Then, at my leisure, I'd try to isolate exactly what it was in the lookup field version which provoked the problem.   The way I've done this before is to load a second instance of the IDE into the IDE and load the project into the second instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the following for narrowing down this error. Set a breakpoint at the function CompareString in Windows.pas. Edit the properties of the breakpoint (advanced) and select "Log Call Stack", clear the "Break" checkbox.

This should print the call stacks to the Messages pane at the point when CompareString is called. When you crash take a closer look at the printed callstacks and see if that is more complete than that in the "Call Stack" pane.